# MySQL 5.7 AUTO_INCREMENT generates duplicate values

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

Today I found a value with duplicate fields in my table, although the field (ID) is auto-incrementing. And through "GROUP BY ...HAVING COUNT" this is not found. Is this a bug?

MySQL 5.7

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=78356

Comment: include `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}`, Include `SELECT VERSION()`, show the evidence in individual results. What SQL statement(s) are used to insert into the table? Edit the question to this information. Welcome to SO. This will probably get migrated to https://dba.stackexchange.com/. Unless you are using <=5.7.17, or where when the data was inserted, the bug report isn't that relevant (see the duplicate linked bug).

Comment: This is impossible. AI must be PK which cannot have dup values without the table damage detection. `GROUP BY ...HAVING COUNT` finds nothing - and I believe it. Maybe you see your client issue?